# Retrieve lost file using Vi in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vim, command-line, editor, vi

I would like to know how to retrieve a file using Vi in MySQL. I logged in using:

```
mysql -uuser -p -hserver -A database
```

Then I do:

```
\e
```

The editor opens and I type my query of 200 lines, then I `:wq` and `\G` (if I save the file it says: `/tmp/sql9SbYQZ saved`) and I see the result.

Now, if I make a mistake or run a different query and I try to type `\e` again, the query is lost.

```
ll /tmp/sql9SbYQZ
ls: /tmp/sql9SbYQZ: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to retrieve the lost file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's what I added to my `.vimrc` in order to save the current query in case i made a mistake.

```
nmap <F7> :w! /tmp/query.sql\| wq!<CR>
```

This will create a map to the F7 key (you can change it of course). So every time you open a file either using `edit` or `\e`, you change it use the <kbd>F7</kbd> key.

This will save a backup of your current query to `/tmp/query.sql` and then save and close the temporary file. This way, if you make a mistake, you just re-open the backup file and try again.

Here's also a link you might like: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_the_last_edited_file

Answer (score 1):

With the vi/m editor used with mysql, crontab, and many others, the work is done in a tmp file, as you see from your messages.

**Edit** (Big doah!, remove cruft about ls -l /tmp/..., you already did that!)

In the future the solution is to tell `vim` to `w` the buffer to a file name of your chosing, i.e.

```
 w! /home/you/scripts/mysql2.sql
```

Then close the editor with

```
 q
```

Note you may not need the `!` after w.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

In Linux, do the following

```
$ cd
$ cp .mysql_history mystuff.txt
$ vi mystuff.txt
```

You should see the file .mysql_history. The mysql client records all queries and commands executed. Hopefully, your query is in there.

Give it a Try !!!